# Why wasn’t it Worf attacking in the Yesterday’s Enterprise timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, time-travel, alternate-history

> **"Federation ship Enterprise, surrender and prepare to be boarded!"**

I love this scene in *Yesterday's Enterprise* and have frequently considered the possibility of Worf delivering that line. Michael Dorn's voice would have been instantly recognizable to fans (that's always fun, to be a bit more in the know than dilettantes watching the show). We never see the Klingon that delivers that line, that would somehow make it more shocking. The best part though would have been the great multileveled nuance that casting would give the next line.

> Picard: **"That'll be the day!"**

It almost feels like the line demanding the Enterprise's surrender was written for Worf.

The only conflict with canon that I can see would be if the attack on the Klingon Outpost Narendra III and the destruction of the Enterprise C happened *after* the Khitomer Massacre. In that case it would stretch incredulity (HA! Like *that* could ever in the Star Trek universe) that Worf could could become a Klingon ship captain. However, the Khitomer Massacre happened (correct me I'm wrong) on 11/10/2346 and the "C" was lost and presumed destroyed on 5/13/2344. Who knows? As long as the Battle of Naredra III happened before the Khitomer massacre, unless I'm missing something, it's anything goes. Maybe in the alternate timeline Mogh was the hero that destroyed the the Romulan Warbirds and saved Khitomer? (That's just a bit of hyperbole, not the question I'm asking)

**The question is**, is there anything I'm missing? Is there any reason (in-universe or otherwise) **NOT** to give that line to Worf?

### EDIT

I'm finding it difficult to understand why this question has been closed as being opinion based. I'm not asking if it's a good idea or if it makes sense. I'm simply asking if there is any reason within canon that Worf could not have attacked the Enterprise during the alternate timeline of Yesterday's Enterprise or if anybody has any inside knowledge of the thinking of the writers.

### FURTHER EDIT - NEW

> MEMO
>
> TO: Rick Berman
>
> FROM: Michael Piller
>
> DATE: Oct 3, 1989
>
> SUBJECT: Pitch
>
> Re: The Time Travel Story “Old Enterprise” by Trent Ganino…what about
> this as a twist… we’re in this routine action story when in flies this
> old Enterprise through a time warp, however we choose, and
> immediately, things change without anyone on board realizing it.
> Picard is still in command..Riker, number one, Data in position, but
> Worf is gone **(in fact a member of an enemy crew)** and Tasha Yar is
> at security…

The above is a quote from The Making of Yesterday’s Enterprise by Eric Stillwell (emphasis mine)

The question of the possibility Worf's involvement in this episode as it relates to Khitomer is uninteresting and circular. As evidenced by the memo quoted above, at least at one point the possibility played in the minds of the series creators. As an answer to this question I would like to know why the creators chose not to use Worf in that way, or if there is a reason within canon that I am missing. Because the Khitomer Massacre happened (in our timeline) long after the events on Nerendra III, it's irrelevant to this conversation.

As written, this question is answerable. As a matter of fact, having found the memo quoted above, I might very well be able to answer this question myself eventually, if the question were reopened.

Comment: It seems to me that any answer to this question would be pure, random, blind speculation.

Comment: @Donald.McLean Not really, is there a conflict with canon that I'm missing? That seems pretty straightforward. As far as (in-universe or otherwise), I'd like to know about any comments the creative team might have made on the subject. There's no way they didn't consider it.

Comment: Dates on Memory Alpha indicate the Enterprise-C was lost in 2346, the same year as the Khitomer massacre.  Where are you getting the specific months/days?

Comment: @Izkata The stardate Picard quotes at the beginning of YE is 43625.2. The calculator hillschmidt.de/gbr/sternenzeit.htm converts that to 8/17/2366. Data says the C was lost 22years, 3mo, 4days prior. That means 5/13/2344. I'm not sure how solid the calculator is, I'm actually planning to make that my next question.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Do a search first, I've answered several Stardate questions on here (short answer: that looks roughly correct, around 2/3rds through the year, but what _exactly_ the "625" means has not been consistent)

Comment: @Izkata Yeah, I just found your long, detailed one. I've read every question tagged TNG, but very little else so I missed it the first time around.

Comment: [This plot summary](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Yesterday's_Enterprise_(episode)#Act_One) says "twenty years previous", but I suppose they could have just cut out part of it

Comment: @Izkata, I just watched the episode 3 times while taking notes. I'm pretty solid on the dates 43625.2 and Data's quote of 22yrs,3mo, 4 days. Also http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Narendra_III quotes 2344 as the year of the attack on Narendra III.

Comment: In-Universe, the USS Intrepid probably wouldn't have responded to a Klingon Distress call if relations between the Federation and Klingon Empire hadn't "thawed" following the Battle of Narendra III (in 2344) therefore Worf would have died on Khitomer Station in 2346.

Comment: @Richard That's making the HUGE assumption that the events on Khitomer happened as they happened in "our" timeline, more than two years after a "non-event" so huge to the history of *that* timeline that its not happening causes 22 years of war. Khitomer not happening at all, or Mogh and family being elsewhere at the time of the attack are completely plausible possibilities.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Any answer to this question would be purely opinion based speculation, unless one of the writers stumbles upon it and decides to definitively answer it. You've already shown that the creative team thought of it in your memo, via what should be a definitive source, and you've pointed out that there is no way to know what happened to the house of Mogh in those 20 something years (for all *we* know Duras killed them all). There is really just no way to know.

Comment: @Xantec But again, you are declaring a question unanswerable *that I didn't ask!* The question is: Is there anything I'm missing? Is there any reason (in-universe or otherwise) NOT to give that line to Worf? I'm continuing my research into the thinking of the writers. THAT may be where the best answer lies. If I do manage to find the definitive answer, I won't be able to post it here because the question has been *wrongly* closed.

Comment: @Jolenealaska - I still don't think your edit is enough.  The memo establishes that he had gone over to the other side for sure, but what is the connection between that and him saying the line?  It's still reading as "this would have been cool so why didn't it happen?"

Comment: @JimmyShelter The interesting question is why *couldn't* it have happened (per canon), or why *didn't* it happen (per the writers). I found that memo in a sneak preview of the book, not available on-line or as an e-book. I'm ordering the damn thing as an actual paper book with a spine. I hope that the book will address the question. I'm disappointed that a question that fascinates me to that degree can't find a home here.

Comment: +1 to Xantec's response. If you're accepting that the changed timeline can alter anything (including known events like Khitomer) then any answer has to be pure speculation. There's certainly no canon answer.

Comment: @Richard So, the answer is "no, no reason" as far as canon. There isn't some obscure thing that I'm missing. Fine, "no, no reason" is an answer to the question, "Am I missing something?". That leaves the other part, "Why did the authors choose to leave Worf out?" There is an answer to that question. I'd like to know.

Comment: In-universe, would a warrior be tasked with using the comms? The production notes state that he's a "member of an enemy crew" and from what we've seen on the show, generally it's either the captain or a female warrior that make contact with alien ships.

Comment: [Related meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3288/1359).

Comment: You should reference the quote. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @bitmask From the book, The Making of Yesterday's Enterprise, by Eric Stillwell. From an online sneak preview of same. Since I was looking at an actual picture of the book, I wasn't able to copy and paste. I had to go old-school and type. When I have the actual print copy of the book, I will provide appropriate footnotes.

Comment: Picard: "That'll be the day!" *vaults up to the tactical position* -- Picard's most badass moment ever?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain the answer is they just didn’t think about it.

However, a plausible answer is that since the Federation ship never rescued Worf he either ended up dead or on the Romulan prison colony.

Comment: Considering over two years between Narendra III and Khitomer, with a history very different from the "real" events, I'm not seeing it as inplausible based solely on the events of Khitomer in "our" timeline.

Comment: As evidenced by the memo I just quoted as an edit to the original question, "they just didn't think about it" is incorrect.

Comment: Actually I think this tracks, though it's a bit under-detailed. Worf's adoptive father was onboard the Intrepid when it responded to the Khitomer situation, which did take place after Narendra III. The likelihood of his taking a Klingon under his wing is far lower in the alt-universe. Chances are Worf ended up with the rest of the hostages in Birthright Pt 2, though it's hard to say for sure.